# How to call function from another component in reactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In reactJs i have two files where one has a utility functionality and another one where i want to use those functionality.

Like an example:

**file1.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class CloseableTab extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = tabs;

        this.addItem = (link) => {
            this.setState({
                activeIndex: this.state.data.length
            });
        };
    }
}

export default CloseableTab
```

So, here in above code you can see i have "addItem" named function or method in the CloseableTab class. [Which contains functionality which i want to use in another file.]

**File2.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import CloseableTabs from '../../containers/CloseableTab/CloseableTab';

class ProductList extends Component {
  this.appendItem = (item) => {
            addItems(item); //here i want to use the functionality method.
        };
}

export default ProductList
```

So, In above file2.js i called addItems with an parameter item, well i know which is not right technique to do. So need help for that.

And want to know how we can call that functionality method [addItem() from file1 ] into file2 while onClick/in onClick's function?

I'll really appreciate your answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to [lift the state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) to one common ancestor:

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = tabs;

        this.addItem = (link) => {
            this.setState({
                activeIndex: this.state.data.length
            });
        };
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <div>
          <CloseableTab tabs={this.state.tabs} addItem={this.addItem} />
          <ProductList tabs={this.state.tabs} addItem={this.addItem} />
        </div>
      )
    }

}
```

Comment: well, Thanks for your help but i didn't get the answer how can i use that addItem functionality into productList component?

Comment: the same way you use props - `this.props.addItem(item);`